# How to get get lat lng X kilometer away from center of circle

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am creating list of circles on my map using a loop. The circle radius may differ for each loop.

The logic should not overlap two circles. For this I need the following :-

- Start with lat lng (circle center) and draw a circle.
- Move radius*2 kilometer ahead and get the center point for second circle and so on.

**Problem :**
 I am facing problem in the second step given above.  How should I calculate the next point(Circle center) in row ? The input that I have is center point of first circle and radius.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The approximate conversions are:

Latitude: 1 deg = 110.574 km

Longitude: 1 deg = 111.320*cos(latitude) km

This doesn't fully correct for the Earth's polar flattening -- for that you'd probably want a more complicated formula using the WGS84 reference ellipsoid (the model used for GPS). But the error is probably negligible for your purposes.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude

So you can calculate the distance you need to move on the map and the latitude, Longitude for the next point on the map.

However there is a library (I have never used it, nut hope it helps)
http://www.jstott.me.uk/jcoord/

Comment: For example : If I have lat lng (-2.54  6.56) and I want to calculate the next point 2000km away to the right of current point. How should I do that ?